# Filtering out columns with zero values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array `A` such as:

```
[[    0.   482.  1900.   961.   579.    56.]
 [    0.   530.  1906.   914.   584.    44.]
 [   43.     0.  1932.   948.   556.    51.]
 [    0.   482.  1917.   946.   581.    52.]
 [    0.   520.  1935.   878.   589.    55.]]
```

I'd like to get a new array that excludes all columns where a 0 appears, that is:

```
[[  1900.   961.   579.    56.]
 [  1906.   914.   584.    44.]
 [  1932.   948.   556.    51.]
 [  1917.   946.   581.    52.]
 [  1935.   878.   589.    55.]]
```

What I've tried is the following:

```
non_zero = np.array([np.all(totals>0,axis=0)]*N_ROWS);
```

Which gives me:

```
[[False  False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  False  True  True  True  True]]
```

Trouble is, doing then `A[non_zero]` returns the expected values *but* rearranged into a one dimensional vector.

So, do you guys know what I'm doing wrong, or if I'm making life over complicated? Thanks!

UPDATE: thanks for all the answers! One short thing in addition to the accepted answer: clearly, aside from the selection itself, I should have used the `:` operand as in:

```
non_zero = np.array(np.all(totals!=0,axis=0));    
a[:,non_zero]
```

And then of course, there's more compact ways (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming here that your values are non-negative:

```
A = np.array([[ 0, 482, 1900, 961, 579, 56.],
              [ 0, 530, 1906, 914, 584, 44.],
              [ 43, 0, 1932, 948, 556, 51.],
              [ 0, 482, 1917, 946, 581, 52.],
              [ 0, 520, 1935, 878, 589, 55.]])

A[:, np.all(A > 0, axis=0)]
```

Which gives me

```
array([[ 1900.,   961.,   579.,    56.],
       [ 1906.,   914.,   584.,    44.],
       [ 1932.,   948.,   556.,    51.],
       [ 1917.,   946.,   581.,    52.],
       [ 1935.,   878.,   589.,    55.]])
```

If you ignore potential precision issues you can replace the condition with `np.any(A == 0, axis=0)`

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this? You can find the indices of columns where there are exactly zero `0`s by summing the number of zeros in each column, and finding which sums are zero:

```
>>> B = A[:, np.sum(A == 0, axis=0) == 0 ]
>>> B
array([[ 1900.,   961.,   579.,    56.],
       [ 1906.,   914.,   584.,    44.],
       [ 1932.,   948.,   556.,    51.],
       [ 1917.,   946.,   581.,    52.],
       [ 1935.,   878.,   589.,    55.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
non_zero = (A != 0)
new = A[:, non_zero.all(axis = 0)]
```